# How to configure a base URL in Apache?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have the following problem:

The Apache DocumentRoot is `/var/www/`.

The URL of the file one should get when browsing http://www.example.com/ is http://www.example.com/_www/en/home.html

So I configured a redirect via a RewriteRule:

`RewriteRule ^$ _www/de/pub/aktuelles.cfm [R]`

Now I don't want the "_www" directory to appear in the URL, but I don't want to rewrite it in every request.

People should see http://www.example.com/en/home.html when they browse to http://www.example.com/

How do I achieve this, I thought of `RewriteBase` but that seems to be something different. But I guess I need some kind of base rule.

Answer (score 0):

To loose the **_www** from the URL simply alter your DocumentRoot to:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/_www/
```

and the Rewrite Rule to match e.g.

```
RewriteRule ^/?$   /de/pub/aktuelles.cfm  [R]
```

If you have multiple language variants of the site you may want to look at using the Apache [MultiViews](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-apache-lang-neg) facility.